# Cancancan - lookup permissions by string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I've used cancancan a lot for checking permissions on specific classes/instances.

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)  
    can do |action, subject_class|
      # Lookup users permission inside of this block.
      # action might be :read
      # subject_class might be a class like Company.
    end
  end
end
```

Above example would for work for `user.can?(:read, Company)`.

I've now created a permission set for multiple classes. My app has multiple settings that I wanted to group under `AccountingSetting` so that I can check the permission via `user.can?(:read, "AccountingSetting")`. Since `AccountingSetting` is not an actual model/class I pass a string to the method.
This does not work since the `subject_class` argument returns `String`-class instead of the actual string.

Is a string lookup for permissions not supported by cancancan or am I missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/Non-RESTful-Controllers.md is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Digged through the docs a bit more and found a solution:

https://rdoc.info/github/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/CanCan/Ability#can-instance_method

The can block returns a third argument, that will include the value of all none class parameters.

```
  def initialize(user)  
    can do |action, class, object|
      # Lookup users permission inside of this block.
      # action might be :read
      # class might be a class like Company
      # object might be nil or a string/symbol.
    end
  end
```

So when `can?(:read, 'AnythingPossibleThingy')` is called, the `object` argument is populated with `'AnythingPossibleThingy'` which I can use to lookup the permissions.